# Calling data from different model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I need to be able to call data from a different model - not just one field, but any of them.

At the moment I have the following models:

```
kase
person
company
party
```

I can call information from the company to the kase and from the person to the kase using this:

```
<li>Client Company Address: <span class="address"><%=h @kase.company.companyaddress %></span></li>
<li>Case Handler: <span><%=h @kase.person.personname %></span></li>
```

Those two work, however if I add the following:

```
<li>Client Company Fax: <span><%=h @kase.company.companyfax %></span></li>
<li>Case Handler Tel: <span><%=h @kase.person.personmobile %></span></li>
<li>Case Handler Email: <span><%=h @kase.person.personemail %></span></li>
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Thanks,

Danny

EDIT: I get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError in Kases#show
Showing app/views/kases/show.html.erb where line #37 raised:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.personname
```

The lines that are noted are as follows:

```
34: <div id="clientinfo_showhide" style="display:none">
35: <li>Client Company Address: <span class="address"><%=h @kase.company.companyaddress  %></span></li>
36: <li>Client Company Fax: <span><%=h @kase.company.companyfax %></span></li>
37: <li>Case Handler: <span><%=h @kase.person.personname %></span></li>
38: <li>Case Handler Tel: <span><%=h @kase.person.personmobile %></span></li>
39: <li>Case Handler Email: <span><%=h @kase.person.personemail %></span></li>
40: </div>
```

The model for the kase is as follows:

```
class Kase
belongs_to :company # foreign key: company_id
belongs_to :person # foreign key in join table
```

The model for the person is as follows:

```
class Person
has_many :kases # foreign key in join table
belongs_to :company
```

The model for the company is as follows:

```
class Company
has_many :kases
has_many :people
def to_s; companyname; end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is their any error message? Can you show us your models and migrations?

Comment: you should have `person_id` on `kases` table.

Comment: I have but it was a string, should it be integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to write a proper answer, the problem was he had the `person_id` on `kases` table as a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the person table populated with data?